# Why didn't Harry summon his broom to fly over the maze in the Triwizard Tournament?

Tags: harry-potter

Wouldn't the best solution have been for Harry to summon his broom to fly over the maze in the Triwizard Tournament?

Comment: Rather than pad-out your question with fluff words, can you outline what you've researched, why you think this should have happened, where you want us to get the information from (is Wikia ok? or only canon stuff?), etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Probably because he was not allowed to

> "**We seemply ’ave to get through the maze?” said Fleur.**
>
> “There will be obstacles,” said Bagman happily, bouncing on the balls
> of his feet. “Hagrid is providing a number of creatures . . . then
> there will be spells that must be broken . . . all that sort of thing,
> you know. Now, the champions who are leading on points will get a head
> start into the maze.” Bagman grinned at Harry and Cedric. “Then Mr.
> Krum will enter . . . then Miss Delacour. But you’ll all be in with a
> fighting chance, depending how well you get past the obstacles. Should
> be fun, eh?”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

When Fleur asks Bagman whether the champions must get *through* the maze, Bagman implicitly replies in the affirmative. He then mentions a number of barriers that champions must overcome. It is not unreasonable for the champions (and the reader) to conclude that the maze must be navigated on foot.

If Harry (or any other champion) had summoned a broom, let alone flown over the maze, they would have been noticed and presumably disqualified.

Comment: Harry didn't follow the rules regarding the first two tasks.  He has a history of not following rules...and he has an invisibility cloak.

Comment: @CHEESE Champions weren't allowed to carry any item to tasks except their wands. Granted Harry could have summoned his Invisibility Cloak, but how would that have helped him? Most creatures that Harry encountered in the maze use their sense of smell at least as much as (if not more than) their sense of sight to locate other animals/creatures (Harry in this case). So the Cloak wouldn't have helped him.

Comment: @ʀᴇᴅ_ᴅᴇᴠɪʟ226 - The supposition is that he could have used his cloak to conceal himself while flying to the Cup. However, I suspect he could *not* do that, since the Cloak has been shown to resist Summoning Spells (not that he knew that at the time).

Comment: Also, that rule was most probably enforced by a magical barrier of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was going to be against the rules I agree and plus it would have been too repetitive of JK Rowling to add him summoning his broom.

Comment: This is a great start to an answer, can you provide references from the books that explain the rules of the maze and why the broom would be against it?